# How do I display role members separately from online members?

Tags: python, discord

I searched for my problem in the [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.administrator), but I didn't find anything.

I want to add a role setting that *"Displays role members separately from online members"*. Even if I can do that manually without programming, I just want to learn and apply it for fun.

This is just a part of my code:

```py
name = discord.Permissions(
    send_messages = True, 
    read_messages = True
) 

await guild.create_role(
    name = "name",
    colour = discord.Colour(0x000000),
    permissions = name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `hoist` parameter to `True` when creating your role as [mentioned in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_role#discord.Guild.create_role).

```py
name = discord.Permissions(send_messages=True, read_messages=True)

await guild.create_role(name="name",colour=discord.Colour(0x000000),permissions=name, hoist=True)
```